# Limit return records to 5 After Summing Up Values

Tags: mysql

Please someone help. I am summing up a group column in this query but the inner query column outside cannot be recognized when i use table alias or even if i didn't use table alias. The intention is to return the record that have highest value after summing and grouping by their name from the first table. The error i got is that the subquery columns that are referenced in the outer query cannot be recognized. It does not recognized them with alias or no alias from subquery.

```
SELECT t1.fullname, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.qty AS 'QUANTITY', t2.value AS 'VALUE', 
YEAR(t2reg_date) AS 'YEAR'
FROM table1 t1  
JOIN  
(
   SELECT col2, col3, SUM(qty) AS 'QUANTITY', SUM(value) AS 'VALUE', 
YEAR(date) AS 'YEAR' FROM table2 WHERE YEAR(date) BETWEEN '2012' AND '2019' AND 
col3 LIKE '%test%' 
GROUP BY foreign_col_id 
HAVING value > 1000000
) t2
ON t1.id = t2.foreign_col_id 
GROUP BY t1.fullname
ORDER BY t2.value DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

I as well observed that SUM() does not work with LIMIT when grouped, it always returns empty set.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @OlammieConcept, would be easier for people to help if you could add https://www.db-fiddle.com/ with sample data and expected output

Comment: how do i add it db-fiddle.com?

Comment: Visit the link -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/ and setup the DB and data there

Comment: please create a separate question for your SUM() not working with LIMIT when grouped, with an example of what you mean

Comment: Post the error message you've received when running the query.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery generates a "table" with column names based on what you select.  You select col2 and col3, so there are "columns" t2.col2 and t2.col3.  But when you specify an alias, as in `SUM(qty) AS 'QUANTITY'`, the alias is used as the column name.  So to refer to that in the outer query, you use t2.QUANTITY.

Comment: Thank you @ysth. See the code below after i edited :  `SELECT ie.fullname, imp.hscode, imp.hsdescription, imp.mass AS 'QUANTITY', imp.fob_value AS 'FOB_VALUE', 
YEAR(reg_date) AS 'YEAR'
FROM ieprofiles ie  
JOIN  
(
   SELECT hscode, hsdescription, SUM(mass), SUM(fob_value), 
YEAR(reg_date) FROM imports WHERE YEAR(reg_date) BETWEEN '2012' AND '2019' AND 
hsdescription LIKE '%cashew%' 
GROUP BY ieprofile_id 
HAVING fob_value > 20000000
) imp
ON ie.id = imp.ieprofile_id
GROUP BY ie.fullname
ORDER BY imp.fob_value DESC
LIMIT 5;` Error is unknown column fob_value in having clause

Comment: Try edit the `SUM(fob_value)` to `SUM(fob_value) AS fob_value` in the subquery

Comment: here you are creating a column accessible as```t2.`SUM(fob_value)` ```, which is very awkward to use; set an alias and use that instead

Comment: Dis query worked but result is wrong. I want the highest value of each group after summing up. `SELECT ie.fullname, imp.hscode, imp.hsdescription, imp.QUANTITY, imp.FOB_VALUE, 
imp.YEAR
FROM ieprofiles ie  
JOIN  
(
   SELECT ieprofile_id, hscode, hsdescription, SUM(mass) AS 'QUANTITY', SUM(fob_value) AS 'FOB_VALUE', 
YEAR(reg_date) AS 'YEAR' FROM imports WHERE YEAR(reg_date) BETWEEN '2012' AND '2019' AND 
hsdescription LIKE '%cashew%' 
GROUP BY ieprofile_id 
HAVING fob_value > 20000000
) imp
ON ie.id = imp.ieprofile_id
GROUP BY ie.fullname
ORDER BY imp.FOB_VALUE DESC
LIMIT 5;
`

Comment: I think maybe you want SUM(imp.QUANTITY) etc, since you are doing a group by in the outer query?  I don't know what you mean by highest value after summing up; please make a new question and provide sample data and expected results for that sample data